# Is Commander Dorne related to Elara Dorne?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

While I was exploring on a Bounty Hunter, the class quest led me to the Imperial Intelligence HQ on Dromund Kaas. When I walked inside, I saw a man named Commander Dorne. Does anyone know if he is related to Elara Dorne, a companion of the Trooper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  Good catch.  According to [this Wikia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vasil_Dorne), Commander Vasil Dorne is her father and an instructor for Sith Intelligence agents.  He also shows up on Vaiken Spacedock as the Imperial Agent's advanced class trainer.

Comment: I wonder if there are any other relative links like this one hidden in the game.

Comment: There are a few, Darth Baras (sith warrior) is mentioned in some convos of other classes, just as an example, there are probably a lot more